# Expresión regular que permita espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber que expresión regular podría utilizar que permita números de 5 o 6 dígitos y que pueda contener espacios en blanco al inicio o al final. Es decir, debe contener 5 o 6 número de 0-9 y cualquier cantidad de espacios. Pongo algunos ejemplos (entiéndase - como los espacios en blanco):

123456
12345
-123456
-12345
--123456
123456-
12345-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\s*\d{5,6}\s*$
```

Explicación:

- ^ = inicio de cadena
- \s = espacio
- * = 0 o N veces el conjunto previo (0 o varios espacios)
- \d = un dígito
- {5,6} = conjunto anterior 5 o 6 veces
- \s = espacio
- * = 0 o N veces el conjunto previo (0 o varios espacios)
- $ = final de cadena